# how do I prevent bootstrap modal close after jquery validation on a form?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

Platform: ASP.NET 4.5, MVC 5, latest jQuery, bootstrap and jQuery validate

My issue is that once I validate the form I'd like to make an ajax call and not close the modal.

Here's my form:

```
<form id="loginform" action="">
    <div id="login-login">
          <span>
            <input type="email" name="login-email" id="login-email" placeholder="my@email.com" />
            <input class="btn btn-success submit" type="submit" id="login-submit" value="Submit" />
          </span>
    </div>
 </form>
```

My jQuery inside my document.ready

```
$("#login-form").popover(); // this is the overall modal id name

$("#loginform").validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            console.log("submit on ok");
            return false;
        }
    },
});
```

**what happens:**

When I enter an invalid email, I see the default jQuery validate fire and show me a friendly message. However, when the entry is correct, I don't see the console.log message (I also used an alert), the modal just closes and I don't want it to. No idea what else I'm supposed to do?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="email" name="login-email" id="login-email" placeholder="my@email.com" />
```

The jQuery Validation plugin is not working properly in your case because...

1. Your element contains `name="login-email"` while you're targeting `name="email"`.  This must match the `name` attribute.

   ```
   rules: {
       "login-email": {  // <- this must match the 'name' of the field
           required: true,
           email: true
       },
       ....
   ```
2. You've incorrectly nested the `submitHandler` within the `rules` option.  This callback is a sibling of `rules`, not a child.

   ```
   rules: {
       ....
   },
   submitHandler: function (form) {
       console.log("submit on ok");  // this now fires on a valid form submit
       // ajax goes here
       return false;
   }
   ```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/2axtuqed/**